# Calling another UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm in a `UITableView` and the user has watched a video.  After the video I would like the user to take a test. Just can't figure out how to call this view controller so I can start the test.

Im in the `PlayListViewController` and want to call the `TestViewController`.

The `TestViewController.h` is imported.  At this stage all there is in the `TestViewController` is what comes with `UIViewController` and some stuff that I added in .xib.  The test coding isn't done yet (that will be the next problem).

I would greatly appreciate if someone has the time to give me directions.

```
-(void) movieFinishedPlaying: (NSNotification *) note {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:[player moviePlayer]];



    [player release];
    NSLog(@"Video has finished playing\n");

    //  To the test

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                                                    message:@"Now for the test!"
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    // Call on test here
    TestViewController *testVC = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:testVC animated:YES];
    [testVC release];


}
```

I have this in the TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {

    UIWindow *tVC;
    UIViewController *testVC;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *tVC;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *testVC;

@end
```

And this in the m file

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation TestViewController
@synthesize testVC, tVC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification before playing video (I guess you are using MPMoviePlayerController to play video, right?):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerViewController];
```

and when it get's fired, present him the instance of TestViewController modally and unregister the notification:

```
- (void)playerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    TestViewController *testVC = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:testVC animated:YES];
    [testVC release];
    [[NSNotification defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerViewController];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, certainly got a bit further on the way.

Comment: What do you mean? If it's not working, can you paste the part of code where you start video?

Comment: Thanks @fichek.  Yes I am using the MPMoviePlayer with notification.  Works really good and I have an alert to show me that I've gone there.  However the new view doesn't show up.  I have done all the setups, I think...

Comment: You insert the first line of code before starting the video playback (I don't know where you do it in your code so I can't tell you exactly where). And the second block of code should just be pasted into your ListViewController.m between any two methods, as well as declared in ListViewController.h as `- (void)playerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;`. If you don't know where to insert what, paste your .h and .m files and I'll show you.

Comment: Oh, that. You put it between the backticks: `

Comment: The notification works fine.  I have an alert showing up once I stop playing the video.  Obviously there is where I have to put the code to switch to the new ViewController.

Comment: `TestViewController *testVC = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:testVC animated:YES];
[testVC release];` should present the test view controller with animation that brings it from the bottom of the screen. I can't tell you more without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry for the code insert.  Didn't quite work out as you guys do it.

Comment: That didn't work at all. I now got errors with "undeclared identifier testVC"  Before I had no errors, just no show.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your code, you have testVC declared in another .h, not the one from ListViewController. Change it back. You still haven't told me if it gives you any warning. It's really weird that it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Changed it back. Absolutely no error and no warnings related to the TestViewController. It's wierd.

Comment: Don't know if it makes any difference, but the PlayListViewController is the main window where the app starts out.

Answer (score 0):

**presentModalViewController** is deprecated in **ios 6** so now it is

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```